# Dynamic Query with if and UNION ALL

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to write a select statement(s) to insert data into a table.
I need to select data from all databases starting with 'Centers' and all tables in those Databases starting with 'AcctHist'.I am using a cross join to get all possible combinations of Databasename.Tablename. However, since all such combinations are not valid, I am trying to check if the table exists before the select. I added this as part of the Dynamic query... but then I get a UNION between if statements.
Is it possible to select from the CTE only valid DB.table combinations? without doing it in the Dynamic query?

```
 declare @tsql nvarchar(max)
 set @tsql = ''

 ;with cte_dbtabnames
 as
 (
     select d.name dbname,t.name tbname
      from sys.databases d
      cross join sys.tables t
      where d.name like 'Centers%'
      and t.name  like 'AcctHist%'
 )

  select @tsql = @tsql + case len(@tsql) when 0 then '' else ' UNION ALL '  end +

   'if object_id(''['+ dbname + '].dbo.['+ tbname + ']'') is not null       begin '+ ' select * from [' + dbname + '].dbo.['+ tbname + '] end' 
  from cte_dbtabnames

 select @tsql
 exec(@tsql)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the system tables to generate your dynamic sql based on the tables found in each database. This code should get you started.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'select DatabaseName = ''' + name + ''', * from [' + name + '].sys.tables t where t.name like ''AcctHist%'' UNION ALL '
from sys.databases d
where name like 'Centers%'

set @SQL = left(@SQL, len(@SQL) - 10)

select @SQL
--uncomment the exec line below when you are comfortable the dynamic sql is correct.
--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```